# How to use promises to do series without duplicate code

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I need execute a code in series, I need execute the same function N times

Example

```
// execute asynFunc 4 times in series
object.asynFunc()
  .then(function() {
    return object.asynFunc();
  })
  .then(function() {
    return object.asynFunc();
  })
  .then(function() {
    return object.asynFunc();
  })
```

I want execute the same function 100 times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a loop.

```
var lastPromise = Promise.resolve();
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    lastPromise = lastPromise.then(function () {
        return object.asyncFunc();
    });
}
```

You could also use [`Promise.reduce`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#reducefunction-reducer--dynamic-initialvalue---promise) over an array with a length of 100 to achieve the same effect.

```
Promise.reduce(new Array(100), function () {
    return object.asyncFunc();
});
```

Comment: @JasonCust if you don't reassign then *all* callbacks will be triggered after the first resolution (i.e. immediately).  Reassigning the last promise allows for chaining which is what the asker wants.

Comment: @JasonCust that is wrong and misleading. ExplosionPills - it's also nice to mention `reduce` here.

Comment: it works!, thanks, there's sme chance for use [.each()](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#eachfunction-iterator---promise) for solvethis?

Comment: @rkmax `.each` will execute in parallel.  I have updated the answer to include an example of `.reduce` which will execute serially.

Comment: I was confused by bluebird .each documentation "Iteration happens serially" said :(

Comment: @rkmax actually confirmed that `.each` *does* work the same way.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ExplosionPills can you write an example using .each? :)

Comment: @rkmax if you just switch `.reduce` with `.each` in my example above it will work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;    
if(count<=100){
  object.asynFunc()
   .then(function() {
     count++;
     return object.asynFunc();
   })
```

This code would execute the function 100 times